# How to do if-else logic on missing optional keyval parameters

Tags: macros, conditionals, xparse, xkeyval

I'm trying to make a macro using the xparse library together with xkeyval for optional key value pairs. Here's a minimal example of what I'm trying to do

cmd.sty

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{cmd}

\RequirePackage{xparse}
\RequirePackage{xkeyval}

\define@key{keyvalTest}{width}{\def\kt@width{#1}}
\define@key{keyvalTest}{caption}{\def\kt@caption{#1}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\keyvalTest}{ o m }{
  \begingroup
    % Set the default values, and override any extra if any optional arguments are present, else just set the default values
    \IfValueTF{#1}
      {\setkeys{keyvalTest}{width={50mm}, caption=\NoValue, #1}}
      {\setkeys{keyvalTest}{width={50mm}, caption=\NoValue}}
      
    \noindent
    Path: #2 \\
    Width: \kt@width \\
    % Should print the caption if specified as an optional arg, else print "No Caption"
    \IfValueTF{\kt@caption}
      {Caption: \kt@caption}
      {No Caption}
  \endgroup
}
```

main.tex

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cmd}

\begin{document}
  \keyvalTest{diagrams/pathToDiagram.pdf} \\
  
  \keyvalTest[caption={hello}, width=3cm]{diagrams/pathToDiagram.pdf}
\end{document}
```

The example gives me this:

[image]

And an error saying that `\NoValue{}` is not defined. I've only seen it used several places ([for example here](https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb31-1/tb97wright-xparse.pdf)), but I've never seen it used in actual code. I suppose it might be deprecated, or is only valid for expl3?

I've been through the [documentation for xparse](https://ctan.uib.no/macros/latex/contrib/l3packages/xparse.pdf) without finding any macro that would act as NoValue. I've also tried reading through its source code, but I would like to avoid expl3 if possible.

I'm wondering where I should go from here. Should I rather be using blank, and using some kind of `isblank` or `isempty` function, or is there a better approach to this problem? I would think doing if else logic on missing named optional parameters would be quite common, but I can't seem to find any examples anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\IfValueTF` is checking whether you have a special character sequence, `-NoValue-` with unlikely category codes set in the argument. Far better is to simply check to see if `\kt@caption` has been set. You can use the internal LaTeX command `\@ifundefined` to manage this by rewritig your definition of `\keyvalTest` as:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\keyvalTest}{o m}{
  \IfValueTF{#1}
  {\setkeys{keyvaltest}{width=50mm,#1}}
  {\setkeys{keyvaltest}{width=50mm}}

  \noindent
    Path: #2 \\
    Width: \kt@width \\
    % Should print the caption if specified as an optional arg, else print "No Caption"
    \@ifundefined{kt@caption}
      {No Caption}
      {Caption: \kt@caption}
}
```

Alternatively, you could use the e-TeX command `\ifdefined` which uses TeX's low-level if mechanism and avoid issues with pre-2018 LaTeXs. Replace the `\@ifundefined` sequence with:

```
\ifdefined\kt@caption
    Caption: \kt@caption
\else
    No Caption
\fi
```

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't mix `xkeyval` with `expl3`, which has its own key-value interface that's in many ways superior to `xkeyval`.

#### File `cmd.sty`

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{cmd}

%\RequirePackage{xparse} % not needed for LaTeX 2020-10-01 or later

\ExplSyntaxOn

\keys_define:nn { hsevenxfour/cmd }
 {
  width .dim_set:N = \l__hsevenxfour_cmd_width_dim,
  width .initial:n = 50mm,
  caption .tl_set:N = \l__hsevenxfour_cmd_caption_tl,
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\keyvalTest}{ O{} m }
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { hsevenxfour/cmd } { #1 }
  \noindent
  Path:~#2 \\
  Width:~\dim_eval:n { \l__hsevenxfour_cmd_width_dim } \\
  % Should print the caption if specified as an optional arg, else print "No Caption"
  \tl_if_empty:NTF \l__hsevenxfour_cmd_caption_tl
   {
    No~caption
   }
   {
    Caption:~\tl_use:N \l__hsevenxfour_cmd_caption_tl
   }
  \group_end:
}

\ExplSyntaxOff
```

#### File `test.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cmd}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\keyvalTest{diagrams/pathToDiagram.pdf}

\noindent
\keyvalTest[caption={hello}, width=3cm]{diagrams/pathToDiagram.pdf}

\end{document}
```

#### Output

[image]